# replace spaces or tabs with semicolon with sed

Tags: sed

how can I replace a tab or empty spaces with a single semicolon?

This is what I'm trying:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/(\s)+|(\t)+/,/g' aws_lab.txt
+/ was unexpected at this time.
```

Thanks

Comment: You need `-r` to use extended regexp.

Comment: Try `s/[<tab><space>]+/;/g` where <tab> and <space> are the single characters they represent

Comment: @aragaer `-r` is GNU sed only, `-E` is also supported by GNU sed but additionally works in OSX sed so is more portable than `-r`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the appropriate POSIX character class:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g' aws_lab.txt
```

Very few seds will recognize the `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and since a tab is one of the characters included in `[:space:]` you dont need to specify it separately. Also, `+` is an ERE metacharacter, not BRE as supported by sed by default so you'd need to add the `-E` arg to sed to use it (only supported by GNU and OSX sed variants).

Comment: Good points, thx, fixed. Yes, I know about `[:blank:]` but it's almost always the case that either the string you are working on does not contain newlines and so whether you use `[:blank:]` or `[:space:]` doesn't matter, or your string DOES include newlines and then you want them treated like every other white space so then you want `[:space:]` instead of `[:blank:]`. So I tend to always use `[:space:]` to represent any white space and just use `[:blank:]` if I have a specific reason to want to exclude newlines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i.bak 's/[ \t][ \t]*/:/' file
```

Or

```
sed -ri.bak 's/[ \t]+/:/' file
```

Where there is an explicit space infront of the tab:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[ \t][ \t]*/:/g' file
```

Will replace repeated patterns throughout a line.